# Problem opening xlsm file

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have some files that are saved a main file.  When I try to open some brings a pop up about enabling macros but the file never displays.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. the first thing you need to do is enable macros. this is a bit different depending on if you are using 2003/2007. you need to go to trust center and adjust your settings.
2. also depending on whether you are using 2003/2007 you need to get into your VBE visual basic editor and you will see all of your code there